# How do I get a public link for my video stored in firebase

Tags: flutter, video, firebase-storage, mux-video

I am using a service called mux in which it takes a url link to a video and encodes transcodes and decodes for you. It takes a link to a video. However how do I get this linke in firebase flutter?

Current This is what I am doing. This leads to the video only showing the first frame.

```
 await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref().child('Users/$currentSignedInEmail/Video/${titleController.text}')
      .putFile(compressedVersion).catchError((error){
   
      });


      //TODO: need to fix this does not load properly
      _muxClient.storeVideo(videoUrl: await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref().child('Users/$currentSignedInEmail/Video/${titleController.text}').getDownloadURL());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      Reference reference = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('Users/$currentSignedInEmail/Video/${titleController.text}');
      UploadTask task = reference.putFile(compressedVersion);
      await task;
      var url = await reference.getDownloadURL();
      _muxClient.storeVideo(url);
```

Comment: Thank you however this did still not work. I get this https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mentorapp-d285a.appspot.com/o/Users%2F2@3.com%2FVideo%2Fjnjk?alt=media&token=1d4737bd-c2f9-4dfd-a44b-8c1e5e2d9fbahttps://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mentorapp-d285a.appspot.com/o/Users%2F2@3.com%2FVideo%2Fjnjk?alt=media&token=1d4737bd-c2f9-4dfd-a44b-8c1e5e2d9fba however I want more like this https://storage.googleapis.com/muxdemofiles/mux-video-intro.mp4 my guess is the .mp4 at the end makes a big difference

Comment: You cant get like this I think

Comment: @AnasNadeem do know any service that will alow me to do this?

Comment: Why not using own hosting server for this?

Comment: @AnasNadeem To be hoenst I do not know where to start with that. Any directions like a tutorial or where to even start?

Comment: You have hosting?

Comment: @AnasNadeem Nope I have no idea where to start nor have anything setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237993/discussion-between-anas-nadeem-and-zach-gonzalez).